# Swipe action in ModalBottomSheet did not really hide it from layout

Tags: android, kotlin

**UPDATE 12/10/2023**

The issue I mentioned in the post is solved. I re-organize the structure of my app, like splitting back-end logic code and front-end UI code using MVVM model. The issue may be related to a chaos in app's structure, but I can not find a way to explain it, so I want to keep this post and wait for someone who can explain to answer.

**Original Post**

Background:

I'm just following the [official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalBottomSheet(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.SheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,kotlin.Function1)) to create a ModalBottomSheet in my app, the thing is that when the ModalBottomSheet was hidden by swiping it, the layout behind the ModalBottomSheet can not be interacted (although the ModalBottomSheet did disappear on visual). And to make it can be interacted again, you will need to press the physical or virtual back button on your device to.

My code:

```
...

var openBottomSheet by mutableStateOf(false)

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
lateinit var bottomSheetState: SheetState

@Composable
fun GradeScreen(
    gradeViewModel: GradeViewModel
) {

    ...

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = true
    )

    // My debug
    Log.d("bottomSheetState", bottomSheetState.currentValue.toString())
    Log.d("bottomSheetState", bottomSheetState.targetValue.toString())
    Log.d("bottomSheetState", bottomSheetState.isVisible.toString())
    Log.d("bottomSheetState", openBottomSheet.toString())
    Log.d("bottomSheetState", "------------------------------------")

    // Main content
    ...
    
    // Sheet content
    if (openBottomSheet) {

        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = {
                openBottomSheet = false
            },
            sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(15.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            ) {
                // Main content
                ...

                // Close button
                FloatingActionButton(
                    // Note: If you provide logic outside of onDismissRequest to remove the sheet,
                    // you must additionally handle intended state cleanup, if any.
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch { bottomSheetState.hide() }.invokeOnCompletion {
                            if (!bottomSheetState.isVisible) {
                                openBottomSheet = false
                            }
                        }
                        ...
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Check,
                        contentDescription = null,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CreateTopBarActionsForGrade() {
    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            openBottomSheet = true
        }
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = rememberFilterAlt(),
            contentDescription = null,
        )
    }
}
```

What I found:

After debugging for a while, I found that it was because when the ModalBottomSheet was hidden by swiping, the value of `openBottomSheet` did not be changed to `false`. I know that the reason that when I clicked the outside of it or clicked the close button to hide it the value of `openBottomSheet` was successfully changed to `false` is that I just writed some codes to implement this operation.

So is there any solution to solve my problem? Any advice will be appreciated.